# Multiplication overflow in C

Tags: c, security, integer-overflow

I'm doing some security CTF practice and have this problem which I am stuck on. This is the C source code of the compiled program:

```
int main(int i, long **a) {
    if(*a[1] * 0x1064deadbeef4601u == 0xd1038d2e07b42569u)
        //exec shell
    return 0;
}
```

Things confusing me:

1. long** main argument won't compile when I turn off gcc flags so I can't reproduce problem on my computer. Is this a different compiler being used? Compiled program runs fine on CTF server.
2. program repeatedly overflows during multiplication before testing equality. I tried using a linear congruence equation (mod 2^64) and extended euclidian algorithm to find the required x input but this did not work for me.

Can someone help me out with this? I'm trying to find *a[1], the correct program argument.

disassembling main in gdb gives:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000040050c <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040050d <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400510 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000400514 <+8>: mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400517 <+11>:    mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
   0x000000000040051b <+15>:    mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040051f <+19>:    add    $0x8,%rax
   0x0000000000400523 <+23>:    mov    (%rax),%rax
   0x0000000000400526 <+26>:    mov    (%rax),%rax
   0x0000000000400529 <+29>:    mov    %rax,%rdx
   0x000000000040052c <+32>:    movabs $0x1064deadbeef4601,%rax
=> 0x0000000000400536 <+42>:    imul   %rax,%rdx
   0x000000000040053a <+46>:    movabs $0xd1038d2e07b42569,%rax
   0x0000000000400544 <+56>:    cmp    %rax,%rdx
   0x0000000000400547 <+59>:    jne    0x400562 <main+86>
   0x0000000000400549 <+61>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x000000000040054e <+66>:    mov    $0x40061c,%esi
   0x0000000000400553 <+71>:    mov    $0x40061f,%edi
   0x0000000000400558 <+76>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040055d <+81>:    callq  0x4003f0 <execl@plt>
   0x0000000000400562 <+86>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400567 <+91>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400568 <+92>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: sorry , updated. i'm trying to find *a[1], the correct program input to make if statement true

Comment: `int main(int, long**)`...

Comment: What do you mean by "long** main argument won't compile when I turn off gcc flags"? It will compile with a warning. It won't compile if you specify the gcc flag `-Werror`. Anyway, you could make gcc happy by specifying `char** argv` and then casting later:  `*(long*)(argv[1])`

Comment: "long** main argument won't compile"

It's because the form is not allowed by standard C, unless the specific compiler allows an implementation-defined form of main. Simply put: the compiler decides the allowed formats of `main()`, not the programmer.

Comment: Also how exactly does `long` multiplied with something, then compared against a literal (`0xd...`) which is larger than the largest value a `long` was ever given in any real-world implementation, `0x7fff ffff ffff ffff`, make any sense? It seems that the code is using completely wrong integer types, making it non-portable and buggy. It should have `uint64_t` type and `ULL` suffix on the integer constants.

Answer (score 3):

There's no real overflow here -- it's just doing a multiply mod 2<sup>64</sup> and testing that the result is what is expected.  To figure out the desired input, you just need to find the inverse (mod 2<sup>64</sup>) of the factor 0x1064deadbeef4601, and multiply it by 0xd1038d2e07b42569

For power-of-2 modulus, it's generally easiest to find the inverse using Euler's formula:

*x<sup>-1</sup> (mod m) ≡ x<sup>φ(m)-1</sup> (mod m)*

when m is a power of two, *φ(2<sup>k</sup>) = 2<sup>k-1</sup>*, so you can calculate this with just *2(k-1)* multiplies.