# Inverse (mod 2^64) of the factor value and mutiplication by value - how to calculate this?

Tags: python, math, assembly

My question comes from [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282672/multiplication-overflow-in-c/32283122#32283122):

> you just need to find the inverse (mod 2<sup>64</sup>) of the factor 0x1064deadbeef4601, and multiply it by 0xd1038d2e07b42569
>
> For power-of-2 modulus, it's generally easiest to find the inverse using Euler's formula:
>
> *x<sup>-1</sup> (mod m) ≡ x<sup>φ(m)-1</sup> (mod m)*
>
> when m is a power of two, *φ(2<sup>k</sup>) = 2<sup>k-1</sup>*, so you can calculate this with just *2(k-1)* multiplies.

I don't understand it. How can I calculate it, for example in Python?

Comment: You're missing some mathematics exponent formatting here, which makes the question look more confusing than it actually is.

Comment: Short answer: `pow(0x1064deadbeef4601, 2**63 - 1, 2**64)`.

Comment: It [works](https://codeshare.io/WdgYB) very well for me. What happens when you try to pass it as input to your program?

Comment: @android_dev: The `pow` solution does work. Please explain more clearly what you tried and what went wrong. After `a1 = pow(0x1064deadbeef4601, 2**63-1, 2**64) * 0xd1038d2e07b42569 % 2**64`, Python gives `True` for `a1 * 0x1064deadbeef4601 % 2**64 == 0xd1038d2e07b42569`.

Comment: Your `main` function has a peculiar signature. How did you even manage to get that to compile? You seem to be expecting the *string* `229526750103728959353476188670814220137` that you pass at the prompt to be magically converted to the correct integer; I don't think that's going to happen. Why aren't you using `scanf` (for example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of 2-adic arithmetic, without worrying about overflow.
for: `r = (x^-1) mod 2^(2^n)`

```
uint64_t r = x;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // (n = 6) for (2^64)
    r = r * (2 - r * x); // ignore overflow.
return r;
```

This method has quadratic convergence. Obviously it requires `x` to be odd for the inverse to exist. In theory, I think `(n - 1)` iterations is sufficient, but I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Agreed about the `n-1` iterations: by picking `r=x` as the starting point, you already have `rx` congruent to `1` modulo `8`, so after `n-1` iterations, `rx` is congruent to `1` modulo `2^(3 * 2^(n-1))`.